# How to write a jpql with left joion

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have such class relationship
ClassA---(Many2One)--->ClassB----(Many2One)-->ClassC

I want to search out A with following conditions
1. C's ID=1
2. C is null

How to write a jpql in such case?

Comment: Conditions:
C's ID=1 Or C is null

Comment: you may find this useful http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/03/25/jpa-outer-join/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JPA 2.1, you can use an ON clause:

```
select a from A a left join a.b b left joib b.c c on c.id = 1
```